# elastic search fetch the exact match first followed by others

Tags: elasticsearch

I am newbie to elastic search

I have an education index in es

[index creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGyhr.png)

when i search 'btech' with match query as

```
"match" : { "name" : "btech" }
```

the result is like

[result json object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l48wz.png)

but i need btech(exact match word) as the first document and remaining documents followed by it.

so for that what i have to change in my index creation

can anybody please help me

Comment: Could you please include curl requests/responses from pictures directly to question. It will make them searchable and will keep them here even if links will stop working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html)

```
"term" : { "name" : "btech" }
```

Or [regexp query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html)

```
"regexp" : { "name" : "btech" }
```

You are using text type, make sure to check [keyword type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) too

from [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html)

> If you need to index structured content such as email addresses,
>   hostnames, status codes, or tags, it is likely that you should rather
>   use a keyword field.